# How to set a maximum integer limit to three so that after pushing a number button for the fourth time, the displayed number wouldn't change?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator that subtracts one `textview` from another. One of the `textview` has a constant value 5. The other `textview` gets its value after a user presses buttons from 0 to 9. There's also a button for a decimal sign (dot). So, for example, if I press buttons 4, 5, ., 6 and 7, the `textview` will show 45.67 and a third `textview` will present the answer (40.67).

This example works fine. But my problem is that I want to limit the number of integers (numbers before the dot) to three. Although I can do this by simply adding `setMaximumIntegerDigits` to 3, it doesn't work as I'd like. For example, if I press 4, 5 and 3, the textview shows 453. That's fine. However, if I then press another number, for example 7, it shows 537. If I press 8 after that, it shows 378, and so on.

The same problem doesn't exist for decimal numbers. So, my question is, how can I set the actual integer limit so that when I press a number for the fourth time, the application wouldn't change the number in `textview`?

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textResult;
private TextView textSubtractor;
private TextView textSubtractee;
private String display = "0";
private String result = "0";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

Button btnDone;
double num1, num2, sub;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    textSubtractor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubtractor);

    textSubtractee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSubtractee);

    btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

    textSubtractor.setText(display);
    textResult.setText(result);

    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("test", 0);
    if (mPrefs != null){
        display = mPrefs.getString("display", "0");
        sub = mPrefs.getInt(result, 0);
    }
    updateScreen();

    btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}

public void onClickNumber(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnDot && (display.equals("") || display.contains("."))) {
        return;
    }

    if ((v.getId() == R.id.btn0 ||
            v.getId() == R.id.btn1 || v.getId() == R.id.btn2 ||
            v.getId() == R.id.btn3 || v.getId() == R.id.btn4 ||
            v.getId() == R.id.btn5 || v.getId() == R.id.btn6 ||
            v.getId() == R.id.btn7 || v.getId() == R.id.btn8 ||
            v.getId() == R.id.btn9) && (display.equals("0"))) {
        clear();
        updateScreen();
    }

    Button b = (Button) v;
    display += b.getText();
    updateScreen();

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);
    df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);

    num1 = Double.parseDouble(display);
    textSubtractor.setText(df.format(num1));

    num2 = Double.parseDouble(textSubtractee.getText().toString());

    sub = num1 - num2;
    textResult.setText(df.format(sub));
}

public void onClickClear(View v) {
    clear();
}

private void clear() {
    display = "";
    result = "";
    textSubtractor.setText("0");
    textResult.setText("0");
}

private void updateScreen() {
    textSubtractor.setText(display);
}
```

Comment: I guess you could make an array with the same length as the amount of buttons and "allocate" them to it. And then add by 1 to the position of the button each time. And before that check if the value at that index is 3. If it's not - then you can add by 1 and do your calculations. Otherwise do nothing (print an error message?).

Comment: Unclear... `integer`? with **decimals**?! Integers don't have **any** decimal, by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution, I would suggest checking the integer and decimal part of the input when new numeric button is pressed:

```
//Class constants
final static int INTEGER_SIZE = 3;
final static int DECIMAL_SIZE = 2;

public void buttonPressed(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_dot){ // Handle dot
        if(!display.contains("."))
            display+=".";
    }else{ // Only number values reach this
        if(display.equals("0")){ // Handle default zero
            clear();
            updateScreen();
        }
        if(display.contains(".")){ //If the number contains a dot, decimal length has to be checked
            String[] split = display.split("\\.");
            if(split.length==2 && split[1].length()==DECIMAL_SIZE)
                return; // New number is not added
        }else if(display.length()==INTEGER_SIZE) //Otherwise check the length of the integer (whole sting)
            return; // New number is not added

        // New number will be added
        Button b = (Button) v;
        display += b.getText();
        updateScreen();

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.FLOOR);

        num1 = Double.parseDouble(display);
        textSubtractor.setText(df.format(num1));

        num2 = Double.parseDouble(textSubtractee.getText().toString());

        sub = num1 - num2;
        textResult.setText(df.format(sub));
    }

}
```

In the long run, you should consider giving user some feedback like disabling the buttons or showing maximum length of the number on UI.